# Is there a way to directly start tomcat with war file argument

Tags: tomcat, server, tomcat7

I hate having to go to UI for Tomcat and re-deploy my application every time I do a compile. Is there a way I can do this while starting up the Tomcat

So something like startup.bat {-argument 'path to war file'}

Thanks in advance

Comment: There won't be, because there can be more than one webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by copying the WAR file to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` and Tomcat will automatically extract the WAR and redeploy it.

Comment: @NickDiv No I don't. It is two keystrokes. Your own suggested command line is far more than either.

Comment: @NickDiv, you can always write a script which copies the WAR to ```/webapps``` once it is given a path argument ;)

Comment: @ShmulikKlein Haha, yeah I was thinking of using AuthHotKey but regardless its a separate thing. I thought I might have missed something in the Tomcat docs to do the 'asked' and thats why I posted this question.